# Can I declare a Razor Pages partial view as internal?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-7.0

My Razor Pages partial view contains:

```html
@model MyPartialModel
```

The model:

```cs
internal class MyPartialModel  { /* ... */ }
```

Since the model is `internal`, I get:

> Inconsistent accessibility: base class 'RazorPage<MyPartialModel>' is less accessible than class 'Pages_Shared_MyPartial'

Can I instruct the razor pages generator to generate the partial as internal?

Comment: Curious, because I’m pretty sure I can use internal classes as models for razor partials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Razor Pages does not provide a direct way to instruct the generator to create partial views with `internal` access modifiers.Razor Pages are, by design, geared towards generating `public` classes for views and partial views. This design choice aligns with the nature of web applications, where views are typically meant to be accessible within the broader context of the application.

To resolve the error you can make `MyPartialModel` public. This would align the accessibility of your model with the accessibility requirements of Razor Pages.

```
public class MyPartialModel  { /* ... */ }
```

If making `MyPartialModel` public is not possible, then you can define a public interface or a base class that `MyPartialModel` implements or inherits from. The Razor Page can then reference this public interface or base class instead of the `internal` class.

```
public interface IPartialModel { /* ... */ }

internal class MyPartialModel : IPartialModel { /* ... */ }
```

Razor Page:

```
@model IPartialModel
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess the answer is "no". It's unfortunate that the generator has this limitation - anything not required for outside use should be internal. I've had other public/internal issues with the generator and opened issues on the repo which they've added to the backlog.